# Accessing playlist on iPod

Tags: ipod, playlists

I've written a little program that reads and converts my local playlists from the iTunes xml (some more background on my blog: [Reading the Playlists from the iTunes Library XML](http://smartercoding.blogspot.com/2009/07/reading-playlists-from-itunes-library.html)).

Now I want to do something similar with the playlists that are stored on my iPod (in my case, a 2nd generation nano; please no iPhone anwers - I'm already envious ;-)). Any legal way to do this?

Comment: The binary format is a bit of a noodle-scratcher, but with any luck at all, opening it in PropertyList Editor should yield some useful information.

Comment: Tried to read the contents with a windows plist Editor, but no luck.

Comment: Ah, that wouldn't do. I was referring to the PropertyList Editor application that comes with OS X as part of the developer tools. I doubt the same precise algorithm would be used in a tool for any other platform (except perhaps GNUStep). You might have to use a Mac for this one.

Comment: The plist Editor claims to be able to read the Mac property lists. So it "should" have been able to read the file if it was in PropertyList format ... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that seems to work is to access the iPod through iTunes. iTunes offers an "older type" COM-based interface (?) called iTunesLib. You can register with Apple to get some documentation, but there is a decent description in [Dan Crevier's Blog on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2004/05/08/128645.aspx).

There must be some other ways though, as there are some alternatives to iTunes that also allow to transfer music to iPods etc. Ideas, anyone? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

OS 3.0 lets you get at the playlist.

Checkout MediaPlayer.h.

Ah, wait. Nano? No, I don't think so. I assumed you meant ipod touch.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still on a nano. Great for jogging! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've dealt with that particular brand of iPods, but if memory serves; if you enable disk mode (if possible), all the info on the iPod will be accessible through a hidden folder on the Volume that shows up in Finder.

Where on that volume the information is I couldn't tell you, but it's probably in there somewhere; most likely in the binary property list format; so the data might take some massaging, but a simple trip through an appropriately factored command line tool should yield the info, or the info in it's XML incarnation.

If, however, the Nano doesn't allow use as a hard disk, I'm afraid there's not likely to be a whole lot to be done for it.

Comment: I can "see" some of the contents of the nano (including a file called iTunes playlists), but the contents seem to be in a binary format. Any description of the format or an API how to read it?